# How can I dynamically populate my table with fetch data from GitHub API?

Tags: javascript, html, github, fetch-api

I'm learning how to fetch data from an API, namely GitHub. I currently have a table like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>GitHub API Fetch</title>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th,
    td {
      padding: 5px;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="activity2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  Enter a valid GitHub user id:
  <input type="text" id="uid">
  <button>Get Details</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <table id="gitTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Repository<br>Name:</th>
        <th>Timestamps:<br>Created &<br>Updated</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Number<br>of forks</th>
        <th>Number<br>of<br>open<br>issues</th>
        <th>HTML URL</th>
        <th>List of Languages<br>Used and URL</th>
        <th>Downloads</th>
        <th>Branches</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
    Please select a third row :
    <select onchange="">
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button onclick="">Refresh</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And I am performing a fetch with this function:

```js
function repositories(username) {
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos`).then((response) => {
        if (response.status !== 200) {
            console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' + response.status);
            return;
        }
        response.json().then((data) => {
            // populate table with a minimum of 2 repos and save remainder into selection dropdown
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
    });
}
```

How can I take the data and only show a minimum of two rows of repositories by default in the table? What I want to achieve then is to then save the remainder of repositories into the dropdown selection, which would then dynamically load the selected repository.

Comment: Would be better if you manage at server side and when loading html page iterate the list with 2 elements you sent from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet below

- fetches the Github repo
- adds two rows to the table (names only)
- adds the rest to the dropdown

```js
function repositories(username) {
  return fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos`)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json()
    })
    .then(json => {
      return json
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
    });
}

const getRepos = async(username) => {
  const ret = await repositories(username)
  return ret
}

(async function() {
  const repos = await getRepos('gegeke')
  // now you have the repositories in the repos const - from here,
  // you can work with it
  // console.log('getRepos:', repos)

  // destructuring the repos array
  // rep1 - first element
  // rep2 - second element
  // repRest - rest of elements
  const [rep1, rep2, ...repRest] = repos
  addTwoRows([rep1, rep2])
  addSelectOptions(repRest)
})();

const addTwoRows = (rows) => {
  rows.forEach(e => {
    const tbody = document.querySelector('#gitTable tbody')
    const tr = document.createElement('tr')
    tr.innerHTML = rowHtml(e)
    tbody.appendChild(tr)
  })
}

const rowHtml = row => {
  html = ''
  html += `<td>${row.name}</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>`
  return html
}

const addSelectOptions = (arr) => {
  const dropdown = document.getElementById('selectDD')
  dropdown.innerHTML = selectHtml(arr)
}

const selectHtml = arr => {
  return arr.map(e => `<option>${e.name}</option>`).join('')
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
Enter a valid GitHub user id:
<input type="text" id="uid">
<button>Get Details</button>
<br>
<br>
<table id="gitTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Repository<br>Name:</th>
      <th>Timestamps:<br>Created &<br>Updated</th>
      <th>Size</th>
      <th>Number<br>of forks</th>
      <th>Number<br>of<br>open<br>issues</th>
      <th>HTML URL</th>
      <th>List of Languages<br>Used and URL</th>
      <th>Downloads</th>
      <th>Branches</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<div>
  Please select a third row :
  <select id="selectDD" onchange="">
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <button onclick="">Refresh</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! Now that the remainder of repos are in the dropdown menu, how would I go about making the selected option add/replace the third row in the table?