# JavaScript not loading HTML file, displays only HTML part

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying Javascript and HTML for the first time so please bear with me if I have made any silly mistakes.

I am trying to fetch JSON from an eternal URL, and display it on my HTML page. I have written a small HTML code, the problem is only the HTML part is working and not the javascript. can you please let me know where I am going wrong?

I cannot see anything in the console if I run this code. but if I just paste the js code in the console it works perfectly.

```js
var staticURL = "http://emis.wbpcb.gov.in/airquality/stndtlsdata?stnid=0017"
console.log('GETJSON')
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  url: 'http://emis.wbpcb.gov.in/airquality/stndtlsdata?stnid=0017',
  status: true
})
// console.log('GETJSON')
$.getJSON(staticURL, function(data) {
  console.log("Inside")
  console.log(data)
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 50%;
}

th {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 6px;
}

td {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Ammonia</th>
    <th>Benzene</th>
    <th>CO</th>
    <th>NO2</th>
    <th>O3</th>
    <th>PM10</th>
    <th>PM2.5</th>
    <th>SO2</th>
  </tr>
</table>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" lang="javascript">
```

EDIT:
After following @mplungjan's instructions, I changed my code to following and it worked perfectly (just posting the JavaScript part which needed some correction):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var staticURL = "http://emis.wbpcb.gov.in/airquality/stndtlsdata?stnid=0017"
    console.log('GETJSON')
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'http://emis.wbpcb.gov.in/airquality/stndtlsdata?stnid=0017',
        status: true
    })
    // console.log('GETJSON')
    $.getJSON(staticURL, function(data)
    {
        console.log("Inside")
        console.log(data)
    }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: Start by changing this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" lang="javascript">` to `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

External Script tags need to be closed and you do not need lang or type

Comment: Also EITHER use $.ajax OR $.getJSON  - if you use $.ajax, you need a success or .done function to process the data

Comment: Also Chrome does not like http URLs and the url you have does not support https

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58911313/how-can-i-dynamically-populate-my-table-with-fetch-data-from-github-api